# Count how many siblings (to the right of current element) contain a specified class in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im working on an example of the prisoner problem.

Basically, 7 prisoners are placed in a line and given a hat of either black or white randomly. Tallest person is at the back and can see all other persons hats right down to the front.

Each person must guess the color of their hat but prisoners cannot speak to each other, they can only say either black or white.

The solution is for the prisoner at the back to say black or white based solely on whether or not there is an even amount of black hats in his line of vision. If number is odd he will guess white and so on until all prisoners have finished.

I can iterate through each of the hats one by one but my main problem is figuring out how the current prisoner can move through the hats in front only and call out black/white solely on whats in their line of vision and whether the amount is odd or even.

> I guess the main piece of the puzzle is to determine how to get all
>   siblings to the right of the current siblings classes and get a
>   running total of all hats with the blackHat class.

```js
var totalEven = 0;

//for each of the <li> elements
$("#list li").each(function() {
  //set range to get random value from array
  var range = Math.round(Math.random() * 1);
  //array of hat classes
  var randomHat = ["whiteHat", "blackHat"];
  //add random class to each <li> element
  $(this).addClass(randomHat[range]);
});

//once elements have been updated
$("#list li").each(function() {
  //get the index of the currently selected li
  var isEven = getIfEven($(this));
  //append result
  $("#resultslist").append("<li class='result'>" + isEven + "</li>");
});

function getIfEven(currentHat)
{
  //here is the main issue
  var totalBlackHats = $(currentHat).siblings().hasClass("blackHat").length;

  //this returns undefined
  console.log(totalBlackHats);
  
  //determine if odd/even
  if( totalBlackHats % 2 )
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

```css
.whiteHat {
  background: white;
}
.blackHat {
  background: black;
}
.hat {
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  margin: 3px;
}
.result {
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
ol{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ol id="list">
    <li class="hat">1st hat</li>
    <li class="hat">2nd hat</li>
    <li class="hat">3rd hat</li>
    <li class="hat">4th hat</li>
    <li class="hat">5th hat</li>
    <li class="hat">6th hat</li>
    <li class="hat">7th hat</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div id="results" class="container">
  <ol id="resultslist"></ol>
</div>
```

It seems that 
  `var totalBlackHats = $(currentHat).siblings().hasClass("blackHat").length;` returns undefined.

Comment: Use filter instead of hasClass.  hasClass returns a boolean.  Or drop the .length if you just need the boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var totalEven = 0;

//for each of the <li> elements
$("#list li").each(function() {
  //set range to get random value from array
  var range = Math.round(Math.random() * 1);
  //array of hat classes
  var randomHat = ["whiteHat", "blackHat"];
  //add random class to each <li> element
  $(this).addClass(randomHat[range]);
});

//once elements have been updated
$("#list li").each(function() {
  //get the index of the currently selected li
  var isEven = getIfEven($(this));
  //append result
  $("#resultslist").append("<li class='result'>" + isEven + "</li>");
});

function getIfEven(currentHat)
{
  //here is the main issue
  var totalBlackHats = $(currentHat).siblings().filter(".blackHat").length;

  //this returns undefined
  console.log(totalBlackHats);
  
  //determine if odd/even
  if( totalBlackHats % 2 )
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

```css
.whiteHat {
  background: white;
}
.blackHat {
  background: black;
}
.hat {
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  margin: 3px;
}
.result {
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
ol{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ol id="list">
    <li class="hat">1st hat</li>
    <li class="hat">2nd hat</li>
    <li class="hat">3rd hat</li>
    <li class="hat">4th hat</li>
    <li class="hat">5th hat</li>
    <li class="hat">6th hat</li>
    <li class="hat">7th hat</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div id="results" class="container">
  <ol id="resultslist"></ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the filter() suggestion that seems to have worked. I also replaced siblings() with nextAll() to only get the next siblings of the current

Comment: @MasterYoda Awesome.